# Does all api request will be served even if server is responding the api slowly

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am making an app in which I am getting thousands of data from Kafka queue and I am sending it to some API's one at a time, if I await for the API to finish sending one data then move to next API it takes lot of time, but when I don't await for API service it is getting done faster, but some-time it gives time out error from the server, is it because I am not awaiting for each request?

```
                          
                 |->sending data to api1(awaiting/not awaiting for API to finish then move to next)
 Kafka queue --->|->sending data to api2(awaiting/not awaiting for API to finish then move to next)
                 |->sending data to api3(awaiting/not awaiting for API to finish then move to next)
```